# `FlatList` is slow to add and remove items as list gets larger

Tags: react-native

I've created a `FlatList` and am cloning an array in the state to add/remove items in it. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, because as the list grows it starts taking longer to add or remove the items (I'm just estimating time from when I tap to when the action happens).

Is there a different way to add/remove items that normal JS array operations? I do this whenever I update my internal list:

```
updateListState = () => {
    this.setState( previousState => {
        previousState.data = this.list.slice()
        return previousState
    })      
}
```

My `FlatList` is configure like this:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={this.renderRow} 
    keyExtractor={ (item) => item.id }
/>
```

Comment: same problem here, using RN 0.51